# Switching from Chrome to Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: vba, powerpoint

As my current script given below is opening in chrome, i needed it opened in Microsoft Edge, tried my luck by googling didn't got any success

```
Sub CoverPageDatabase()

  Dim chromePath As String

  chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""

  Shell (chromePath & " -url http://www.stackoverflow.com/")

End Sub
```

Please help me to get the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CoverPageDatabase()
    Dim EdgePath As String
    Dim sUrl As String
    
    EdgePath = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe ""microsoft-edge:"""
    sUrl = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    
    Shell (EdgePath & sUrl)
End Sub
```